# Google maps DirectionsRenderer

Tags: google-maps, marker

I'm looking to change the marker icons of the google map, while creating a path using DirectionsRenderer. Trying to do that, i followed following steps.

- created two icons for the start point and the end point.
- in rendererOptions set suppressMarkers: false
- then placed those two marker to the start point and the end point of the path

So now I have my customary created icons at the two ends.

But my requirement is these markers should be draggable. so i set the **draggable: true** and now its working fine.

But now my problem is while dragging the icon, the path should be changed dynamically, which should be similar to that of 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

I tried to do this by adding listeners to those two markers : "drag" event - and while dragging a marker, draw the path at the same time. But the result I'm getting is not similar to the "directions-draggable" example. In facts, although i can render paths, previously drawn paths still exist on the map. But clearing all the paths exist on the map and then re-draw all is not my requirement.

So is there a way to get the same result/effect like the "directions-draggable" while changing the marker icons.

thanks in advance...

Comment: The routing engine that calculates the paths is the same, so if you drag in the same way you should see the same results. In what way is your result different from the Google demo? Can you post a link to a page that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example of [directions using custom icons which are draggable](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_icons_draggable.html) was developed before the draggable directions functionality was introduced.

**code snippet:**

```js
// this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar 
var side_bar_html = "";

var gmarkers = [];
var map = null;
var startLocation = null;
var endLocation = null;
var directionsService = null;
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: [],
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeWeight: 3
});

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(24.7756, 121.0062);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var request = {
    origin: "532 Beacon St., Boston, MA",
    destination: "77 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA",
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, RenderCustomDirections);
}

function RenderCustomDirections(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var route = response.routes[0];
    var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
    var detailsPanel = document.getElementById("direction_details");
    startLocation = new Object();
    endLocation = new Object();

    summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
    detailsPanel.innerHTML = '<ul>';

    // For each route, display summary information.
    for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
      var routeSegment = i + 1;
      summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
      summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
      summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
      summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
    }
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
    for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
        startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
        startLocation.marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green");
      }
      endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
      endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
      var steps = legs[i].steps;
      for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
        var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
        detailsPanel.innerHTML += "<li>" + steps[j].instructions;
        var dist_dur = "";
        if (steps[j].distance && steps[j].distance.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;" + steps[j].distance.text;
        if (steps[j].duration && steps[j].duration.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;" + steps[j].duration.text;
        if (dist_dur != "") {
          detailsPanel.innerHTML += "(" + dist_dur + ")<br /></li>";
        } else {
          detailsPanel.innerHTML += "</li>";

        }
        for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
          polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
          bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
        }
      }
    }

    detailsPanel.innerHTML += "</ul>"
    polyline.setMap(map);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    endLocation.marker = createMarker(endLocation.latlng, "end", endLocation.address, "red");
    // == create the initial sidebar ==
    makeSidebar();
  } else alert(status);
}

var icons = new Array();
icons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/marker_red.png",
  // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
  new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
  new google.maps.Point(9, 34));

function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
  if ((typeof(iconColor) == "undefined") || (iconColor == null)) {
    iconColor = "red";
  }
  if (!icons[iconColor]) {
    icons[iconColor] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/marker_" + iconColor + ".png",
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
  }
  return icons[iconColor];

}
// Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
// where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
// in the top left of the image.

// Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
// increase in the X direction to the right and in
// the Y direction down.

var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapIcons/marker_red.png',
  // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
  new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
  new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
  // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
  // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
  new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
// Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
// The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
// traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
// coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
// coordinate.
var iconShape = {
  coord: [9, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 14, 2, 16, 5, 19, 7, 23, 8, 26, 9, 30, 9, 34, 11, 34, 11, 30, 12, 26, 13, 24, 14, 21, 16, 18, 18, 16, 20, 12, 20, 8, 18, 4, 16, 2, 15, 1, 13, 0],
  type: 'poly'
};
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

function createMarker(latlng, label, html, color) {
  var contentString = '<b>' + label + '</b><br>' + html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    shadow: iconShadow,
    icon: getMarkerImage(color),
    shape: iconShape,
    title: label,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });
  marker.myname = label;
  gmarkers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    var request = {
      origin: startLocation.marker.getPosition(),
      destination: endLocation.marker.getPosition(),
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };
    startLocation.marker.setMap(null);
    endLocation.marker.setMap(null);

    gmarkers = [];
    polyline.setMap(null);
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [],
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeWeight: 3
    });
    directionsService.route(request, RenderCustomDirections);

  });

  return marker;
}

function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}
// == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
function makeSidebar() {
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
  }
  document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places,drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
<div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="direction_details" style="margin:20px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="side_bar" style="margin:20px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```